# Angular 4 calling variable from another component not update the value?

Tags: angular, lodash

productFilterComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ProductFilterService} from '../../services/product_filter.service';
import {ProductService} from "../../services/products.service";
import {NormalproductfilterComponent} from "./normalproductfilter/normalproductfilter.component";
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productfilter',
  templateUrl: './productfilter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productfilter.component.css'],
  directives: [NormalproductfilterComponent]
})
export class ProductfilterComponent implements OnInit {

  brands: any;
  products: any;
  filter_products: any;

  filtered_result = [];
  selected_brands = [];
  Data: any = [];

  color: any[] = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "grey", "yellow", "gold"];

  constructor(private _products: ProductService, private _productBrands: ProductFilterService, private normalProduct: NormalproductfilterComponent) {
  }

  getAllBrands() {
    this._productBrands
      .getAllBrands()
      .subscribe(brands => {
        this.brands = brands.Data;

        this.brands.forEach(singleRecord => {
          if (singleRecord.parent == 0) {
            this.Data[singleRecord.name] = singleRecord.id;
          }
        })
      })
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this._products
      .getAllProducts()
      .subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products.Data;
        console.log(this.products);
      });
  }


  // Getting Selected Games and Count
  getSelected(val, event) {
    var index = this.selected_brands.indexOf(val);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.selected_brands.push(val);
    } else {
      this.selected_brands.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(this.selected_brands);
    for (let temp of this.products) {
      if (this.selected_brands != '' || temp != 'undefined') {
        for (let temp2 of this.selected_brands) {
          this.filter_products = _.filter(temp.categories, {'id': temp2});
          if (this.filter_products != '') {

            var indexofFilterProducts = this.filtered_result.indexOf(temp);
            if (indexofFilterProducts === -1) {
              this.filtered_result.push(temp);
            } else {
              this.filtered_result.splice(indexofFilterProducts, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        this.filtered_result = this.products;
      }
    }

    this.normalProduct.products = this.filtered_result;
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllBrands();
    this.getAllProducts();
    }
  }
```

This is my product filter file i want to update the value of products on another file that is 
normalProductFilter.ts

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {ProductfilterComponent} from '../productfilter.component';
import {ProductService} from "../../../services/products.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-normalproductfilter',
  templateUrl: './normalproductfilter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./normalproductfilter.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class NormalproductfilterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() data: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  products: any;
  data:any;
  normal_products_image: any[] = ["prdct1", "prdct2", "prdct3", "prdct4", "prdct5", "prdct6", "prdct7", "prdct8", "prdct1", "prdct2", "prdct3", "prdct4",];

  constructor(private _normalProducts: ProductService) {
  }

  getAllProducts() {
    this._normalProducts
      .getAllProducts()
      .subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products.Data;
        console.log(this.products);
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProducts();
  }
}
```

I want to change the value of products using filter as per user selection i got values from function but when I am trying to update it through productFilter then its not working.

Comment: Please provide more explanations and a reproduction could be useful, can you reproduce your issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) please?

Comment: I am unable to access "products" variable from normalProductFilter.ts in productFilterComponent.ts

Comment: I'm not sure how you're trying to do it, nor have I transferred data between components directly, but a way of doing it would be to create a service with a variable, say var. Then from NormalproductfilterComponent, populate var and then retrieve the value of var into products in productFilterComponent

Comment: I want to access the products which was present in normalFilter.ts and i want to access the products in productFilter.ts but it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new service (type `ng g service <yourServiceName>` into your terminal). In the service:

```
products:any;
holdProducts(pProducts: any){
 this.products=pProducts;
}
retrieveProducts(){
 return this.products;
}
```

Now call holdProducts() from the component where you want to store the value, passing `products` as a parameter. In the component to retrieve, call the retrieveProducts() function and store it in the variable.

You could set a flag or check somehow before retrieving, in the 2nd component, that the value has been populated (or maybe incorporate that logic into retrieveProducts())

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already fetch the all products using service now i want filter my product i filter it and now i want to display filtered product on my site using products variable but i cannot access it.

Comment: Is this your scenario: You accept products in component A, then filter the products in component B and then want to display the products back in component A?

Comment: Ok, then after filtering products in component B, call the holdProducts() method and retrieve it back in A. Is there any reason why you dont want to do this (maybe for eg., bec you dont want to jump back and forth between components)?

Comment: how i call retrieveProducts() method in A.

Comment: Same way as you do in B. To access methods from a service, you need to "inject" the service into the component. Then you can use the method that belongs to the service , inside the component. For eg. if you have a service called service1 that contains a method method1, then after you inject the service in the component's constructor, you can simply call the method as: service1.method1()

Comment: but i want to call retrieveProducts()  after the filter function so how can i do that..?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your code and post the link here